# Visual Studio Code Intellisense and includePath

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, intellisense, include-path

I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio Code with the C/C++ extension on Linux. I'm trying to figure out why it is having problems finding my include files.

In one .c file it shows the following:

```
#include "tournament.h"
#include "layout.h"
#include "random.h"
#include "paytable.h"
#include "widgets.h"
#include "sound.h"
#include "leaderboard.h"
```

`tournament.h` and `sound.h` are highlighted saying Code can't find these files even though they are in the same directory as the other included files.

I've gone into c_cpp_properties.json and edited the Linux section and added include path directories as follows:

```
{
    "name": "Linux",
    "includePath": [
        "/home/jnorton/build.kgisystems/src/svn/tournament/trunk",
        "/usr/include/atk-1.0",
        "/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include",
        "/usr/include/glib-2.0",
        "/usr/include/gtk-2.0",
        "/usr/local/include",
        "/usr/include",
        "/usr/include/bits",
        "/usr/include/c++/7",
        "${workspaceRoot}",
        "/usr/include/c++/7/tr1",
        "/usr/include/c++/7/x86_64-redhat-linux",
        "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
        "/usr/include/pango-1.0",
        "/usr/include/cairo"
    ],
    "defines": [],
    "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
    "browse": {
        "path": [
            "/home/jnorton/build.kgisystems/src/svn/tournament/trunk",
            "/usr/include/atk-1.0",
            "/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include",
            "/usr/include/glib-2.0",
            "/usr/include/gtk-2.0",
            "/usr/local/include",
            "/usr/include",
            "/usr/include/bits",
            "/usr/include/c++/7",
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "/usr/include/c++/7/tr1",
            "/usr/include/c++/7/x86_64-redhat-linux",
            "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
            "/usr/include/pango-1.0",
            "/usr/include/cairo",
            "/home/jnorton/build.kgisystems/src/svn/tournament/trunk"
        ],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false,
        "databaseFilename": ""
    }
},
```

I've followed the [guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/FAQ.md#why-do-i-have-red-underlines-everywhere-after-updating-to-the-latest-version) and Intellisense is still not working properly.

What am I missing?

Comment: What does the "not working properly" look like? @Chimera

Comment: @ifconfig Code isn't finding my include files. Put squiggles underneath includes that are in a path specified in the c_cpp_properties.json file.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this line to settings.json it seemed to work for me:

```
"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser",
```

It seems to allow IntelliSense to provide fuzzy results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Visual Studio Code and getting the same issue with gtk/gtk.h

to with:

> [Running] cd
>   "/home/rion/VisualStudio_Workspaces/Configurator_Workspace/" && g++
>   ConfiguratorWindows.cc -o ConfiguratorWindows &&
>   "/home/rion/VisualStudio_Workspaces/Configurator_Workspace/"ConfiguratorWindows
>   ConfiguratorWindows.cc:1:15: fatal error: gtk: No such file or
>   directory compilation terminated.
>
> [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.045 seconds

And I've done all the things - adjusted the include path thing, even explicitly wrote the entire path in the `#include <>` tag, prayed to The Old Ones...

There's a strange smell of burning rubber and some odd groaning coming from a closet upstairs, but the path is still not resolving.